# Win7, add route with netsh without mentioning interface

Tags: windows-7, netsh

I want to make a script for my team to add routes, but as each computer has its own set of interfaces so I can't know interface name/ID in advance.
Is it possible to do with netsh(I know how to do it with 'route add')?

Here is how I tried

> netsh interface ipv4 add route 1.2.3.0/24 nexthop=2.3.4.5 store=active

One or more essential parameters were not entered.
Verify the required parameters, and reenter them.
The syntax supplied for this command is not valid. Check help for the correct syntax.

Only one interface connected to this gateway, so there is no doubt how it could be configured